Is there a LEGO element that is like Technic brick with multiple holes, but with one long slit instead?
I need a LEGO Technic brick like this one:  But with one long slot instead of the holes separate?

It does not @IvanSanchez

@JamesMckibben : then you'll have to clarify your question, because it does look like the same question to me as well.

Well, that answer lists the best elements you can get. But lets be fair, it is impossible to have Technic brick with a slit along entire its length - this bricks structural integrity will be easy to compromise (twist, bend, break) which LEGO will never allow. If that is the kind of element you are looking for - you'd need to look either to adapt elements mentioned in another answer or come up with different solution.

I've some, don't know what called, or use apart from as normal bricks.

@JamesMckibben Note that the "does this answer your question" bit is a pleasantry added automatically when marking a question as duplicate. Fact is, your question is pretty much the same as the linked one, and asking it again will not yield any new/better answers.


Don't know what it is called or its uses apart from as a normal brick. I've also some 1×12's with a wavy slit.
PS. not sure it is Lego?

Well, LEGO has made https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2653&name=Brick,%20Modified%201%20x%204%20with%20Channel. Whether your picture shows that or a clone part is impossible to say based on a bad picture from one angle. But the channel on that does not go all the way through as the holes of a Technic brick and as I thought the OP wanted. The closest I can think of with dimensions close to 1x12 is: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4217&idColor=1#T=C&C=1

Thanks, called a channel, not a slit, & see I've 1×14, not 12.
